# Why isn't my JFrame repainting like I told it to?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

When instantiating my modified `JPanel` class, I pass in a file through the constructor. The file (XML) gets read and the data gets used by me later in the `paint` method. However, right after I parse the data, I call both `repaint()` and `revalidate()`, but my GUI looks exactly the same. I call these methods both in my main class which extends `JFrame` and my panel class which extends `JPanel`.

When I choose an xml file from my `JFileChooser`, the `drawPanel` class gets instantiated with its other constructor, taking in the file and parsing it, then calling `repaint` and `revalidate`. I omitted most of the code to save your time.

Here's the main class' code:

```
public class myCode extends JFrame {
  public myCode() {
    super("Roadway Simulator");

    setSize(800, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    drawie = new drawPanel();
    drawie.setSize(new Dimension(width - 200, height));
    drawie.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width - 200, height));
    drawie.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width - 200, height));
    drawie.setLocation(0, 0);
    add(drawie);

    setVisible(true);

    try{Thread.sleep(500);revalidate();repaint();}catch(InterruptedException eeee){}
}
  public static void main(String[] args){new myCode();}
}
```

Here's my drawPanel class:

```
class drawPanel extends JPanel {
  boolean drawRoad = false;
  public drawPanel() {
    super();
  }
  public drawPanel(Document doc){
    super();
    //the change in my paint method
    drawRoad = true;
    revalidate();
    repaint();
  }
  public paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    if(drawRoad){
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
    }
  }
}
```

My code is the same as above, just with a lot more detail. Why isn't my JFrame repainting?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) - but in your case, since you're using a `null` layout, they will have no effect anyway...

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
try{Thread.sleep(500);revalidate();repaint();}catch(InterruptedException eeee){}
```

Understand what `Thread.sleep(...)` does to a Swing GUI when called on the Swing event thread -- it puts the current thread which happens to be the Swing event thread, the one responsible for all drawing and user interaction, to sleep. In other words, you put your entire application completely to sleep.

Solution -- don't call this **ever** on the event thread.

As an aside, there's no cost to putting each method call on its own line, and no reason for that long line that you've posted as it serves no purpose other than to confuse.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: we're seeing a lot of this, for sure.

Answer (score 4):

`try{Thread.sleep(500);revalidate();repaint();}catch(InterruptedException eeee){}` is most likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing from processing the Event Queue and making it look like your program has hung.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details...

It is also not recommended to override `paint` of Swing components and instead use `paintComponent`, see  [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

In your case, I would recommend using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `Thread.sleep`, see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

**Updated**

I don't see any where in your code that would change `drawRoad` from `false` to `true`, so your `paint` method is painting...nothing...so I guess you frame is painting exactly the way you told it to...

You may also like to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and you might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

**Updated**

Given that you example is incomplete and won't compile, when I rebuild it, this will work...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class TestDraw extends JFrame {

    public TestDraw() {
        super("Roadway Simulator");

        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DrawPanel drawie = new DrawPanel(null);
        add(drawie);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new TestDraw();

            }
        });
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        boolean drawRoad = false;

        public DrawPanel() {
            super();
        }

        public DrawPanel(Document doc) {
            super();
            drawRoad = true;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            if (drawRoad) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `DrawPanel drawie = new DrawPanel(null);` to `DrawPanel drawie = new DrawPanel();` it still paints, but doesn't perform your custom painting.

The other problem is, as has already been highlighted, is the use of `null` layouts

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.

Have a look at [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more details...

Now, having said that, when you add `drawie`, you never give it a size, Swing is smart enough not to paint `0x0` sized components...

Comment: Even without the Thread.sleep(500); my GUI still does not update

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant: indeed, you never call the constructor that changes its state. You only call the default constructor, the one that takes no parameters. And that one does not change drawRoad.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant Well, that's not helping either of use, your example should be able demonstrate your workflow and your problem...